# Builds failing on random in readthedocs

Tags: python-sphinx, read-the-docs

There seems be an odd problem with Readthedocs. Builds are failing without any apparent reason. On the same commit ID, build failed once and was success later:

Failure: https://readthedocs.org/projects/opnfvdocsdemo/builds/4909528/
[image]

Success: https://readthedocs.org/projects/opnfvdocsdemo/builds/4911183/
[image]

My most recent build is failing too, it only has an extra space from the last successful commit: https://readthedocs.org/projects/opnfvdocsdemo/builds/4915952/

This is happening for multiple projects of mine. Whats the issue? Is it a bug from readthedocs or its something with my code?

Comment: Also see: https://github.com/rtfd/readthedocs.org/issues/2591

Comment: Yes, I reported it to RTD in their issue tracker. No reply so far.

Comment: I'm having this issue now. It sounds a lot like github.com/rtfd/readthedocs.org/issues/2591. I'm doing a bit more troubleshooting, but will reopen that issue if I can't resolve.