# Readthedocs build fails on reading sources without error

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-sphinx, read-the-docs

I'm using readthedocs with sphinx autobuild with documenation for my python project.

Buidling the html works on every local environment I tried it on, and past versions have worked. Previously, when there were errors, they were clear and fixable.

However, this time, this is the only output on the failing section:

> Running Sphinx v1.3.5
>
> making output directory...
>
> loading translations [en]... done
>
> loading pickled environment... not yet created
>
> loading intersphinx inventory from https://docs.python.org/objects.inv...
>
> building [mo]: targets for 0 po files that are out of date
>
> building [readthedocs]: targets for 9 source files that are out of date
>
> updating environment: 9 added, 0 changed, 0 removed
>
> reading sources... [ 11%] api
>
> reading sources... [ 22%] core
>
> reading sources... [ 33%] core/notification
>
> reading sources... [ 44%] core/parser
>
> reading sources... [ 55%] core/plugin_handler
>
> reading sources... [ 66%] index
>
> reading sources... [ 77%] tools
>
> reading sources... [ 88%] web
>
> reading sources... [100%] will

And then it just fails.

The code is at https://github.com/ironman5366/W.I.L.L

Comment: "And then it just fails". Aren't there any error messages?

Comment: No, that's my problem. Absolutely no error messages. It just gets there and stops and says "build failed"

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/41735762/407651

Comment: @mzjn Possibly but that screenshot showed an "Unexpected error" box that I don't have. [What I'm seeing](http://imgur.com/a/oJxma)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don't know what caused this, but [it suddenly started working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BWf5i.jpg). I didn't change anything in the rst files or build config, so it's a mystery to me.

I'll assume whatever caused it is fixed.